# Split with and get Results from T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, split

I have some T-SQL code that pulls information from a SQL Server table. I need to parse a column and display according to following result set. I'm bew to SQL, it would be great if you don't mark as duplicate and show me how to do it.

Can you please help?

```
SELECT Account, CTSFirm, AccountName, BOCodeGMI 
FROM StagingEDFACRRBO
```

`BOCodeGMI` column contains:

```
e=01:c=KW:m=10000
c=C-:e=01:m=10000
c=S-:e=01:m=10000
c=06:e=01:m=10
c=07:e=01:m=100
c=W-:e=01:M=10000
```

Logic to split `BOCodeGMI` and display two separate columns `BOCodeGMI_1` & `BOCodeGMI_2`:

- If string contains `e=` then display `BOCodeGMI_1` as its corresponding value (ex: `01`), if string doesn't contain `e=`, then display `BOCodeGMI_1` as NULL
- If string contains `c=` then display `BOCodeGMI_2` as its corresponding value (ex: `C-`), if string doesn't contain `c=` then display `BOCodeGMI_2` as NULL

Finally this is how it suppose to show -

```
BOCodeGMI            BOCodeGMI_1          BOCodeGMI_2 
-----------------------------------------------------
e=01:c=KW:m=10000    01                   KW
c=C-:e=01:m=10000    01                   C-
c=S-:e=01:m=10000    01                   S-
```

Comment: Is the length of string that want to extract equals always 2 ?

Comment: Yes, we can assume, it would be 2 for now.

Comment: check my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next query via using [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) & [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
SELECT 
    BOCodeGMI,
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('e=', BOCodeGMI) > 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING (BOCodeGMI, CHARINDEX('e=', BOCodeGMI) + 2 , 2) 
    END as BOCodeGMI_1,
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('c=', BOCodeGMI) > 0 
           THEN SUBSTRING (BOCodeGMI, CHARINDEX('c=', BOCodeGMI) + 2, 2)
    END as BOCodeGMI_2
FROM
    tableName
```

`CASE` to go through conditions and return a value.

`CHARINDEX` to search for a substring in a string, and returns the position.

`SUBSTRING` to extract some characters from a string.

Comment: Fantastic Job. You rock!